# how to multiply the array element in to the next element and output as an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var numbers = [2, 4, 3, 7]
var computed = numbers 
print(computed)
```

I want to multiply the first element to next, until the last will multiply to the first element

example:
`2*4, 4*3, 3*7, 7*2`

and the output will be `[8, 12, 21, 14]`

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Working with Arrays in Swift](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/232542/35991) on Code Review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the Swift language but the algorithm is pretty simple and does not depend on any technology. Try with this one:

```
let numbers = [2, 4, 3, 7]
let indexAndNum = numbers.enumerated().map { (index, element) in
    return element * numbers[(index + 1) % numbers.count]
}
print(indexAndNum)
```

Live demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/NearSpicyHypothesis)

Comment: Thanks! Language is just a way to tell the computer what we think, right? ;) I like to try new things

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultArray = [Int]()
for (index, number) in numbers.enumerated() {
     if index < numbers.count - 1 {
         resultArray.append(number *  numbers[index + 1])
     } else {
         resultArray.append(number *  numbers[0])
     }
}
print(resultArray)
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Succincter version of Sebastian Kaczmarek's answer:-

```
let numbers = [2, 4, 3, 7]
let computed = numbers.enumerated().map { $1 * numbers[($0 + 1) % numbers.count] }
print(computed)
```

Output:-

```
[8, 12, 21, 14]
```